# Using same argument multiple times in .before() does not work as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

HTML:

```
<div class="here">This is here</div>
<div class="insert">This is to be inserted</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $m = $(".insert");
  $(".here").before($m);
});
```

It produces the expected result - cuts the `insert` div and pastes it before the `here` div. But if the code is as following,

```
$(".here").before($m, $m);
```

then `insert` does not appear twice before the `here` div. However if I use as the second argument a `div` other than the first one in the following way :

```
$(".here").before($m, $('<div class="insert2">This is insert 2</div>'));
```

then both `insert` and `insert2` `divs` appear before the `here` `div`.

Why don't two `divs` appear before the `here` `div` if the two arguments are  same?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/before/: _“If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved before the target (not cloned).”_ And the way you are using it here, exactly that happens twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give an existing DOM element as an argument to DOM insertion methods, it doesn't make a copy of the element, it just moves that element to the place you specify. A single DOM element can only be in one place at a time, so if you specify the same element twice, it moves it twice. If you want copies of the element, you must make them explicitly:

```
$(".here").before($m, $m.clone());
```

Comment: 'so if you specify the same element twice, it moves it twice' - and in the second move, it gets no element in the DOM to move as the element was removed from that location previously , right ?

Comment: No, it moves it from where it started to before `.here`, then it moves it from the new location to before `.here` again. The second move doesn't do anything, since it's already there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is moving an existing element from one place to another; you are not creating additional copies of it. Create copies using `.clone()` method and insert into desired location:

```
$(".here").before(
    $m         /*.attr("title", "original")*/,
    $m.clone() /*.attr("title", "copy # 1")*/,
    $m.clone() /*.attr("title", "copy # 2")*/
);
```

Your other example creates a new element which is why it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because an element can exist just once.
With `$(".here").before($m, $m);` You say insert element_x before '.here' and than insert element_x before '.here'. So it is moved and than moved again to the same place.

With `$(".here").before($m, $('<div class="insert2">This is insert 2</div>'));` you're creating a new element in the second parameter so that works fine.

To copy an element to insert it twice you can clone the element and insert both:

```
var $m2 = $m.clone();
$(".here").before($m, $m2);
```

Comment: 'and than moved again to the same place.' - is it ? or the second selection just gets no DOM element ?

Comment: There is no second selection. It is the same element that it's pointing to.